# Mysql lost privilegies after reboot

Tags: mysql

I use MYSQL 8.0.27 and Ubuntu. My problems are user's privileges. I can create and connect to database. It's ok. But when i reboot the machine, the user's privileges lost.

Example create user:

```
CREATE USER 'usuario'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON bbdd.* TO 'usuario'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='usuario';
```

If i show privilegies for usuario. I see that ok. But if i reboot my machine and again i show the privilegies mysql says  `There is no such grant defined for user 'usuario' on host '%'`

Comment: I create the same user but host="localhost" and when i reboot i don't lost the privilegies for that user. 

CREATE USER 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
...

Comment: Try this test: `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;` Do you see your 'usuario', '%' user?

Comment: Yes, when i create user i see in SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;

Comment: Okay, unless it's something strange (e.g. you typed a unicode character that visually appears to be '%' but is actually a different character), I can't think of how a user could exist in the system table `user` but not show any grants.

Comment: My problem is the host "%". If if create any user with define host, example "14.14.14.13" and i give it privileges. If i reboot my system, the privileges not lost.